# How to pass images between C# and Ironpython with opencv (or Emgucv)

Tags: c#, python, wpf, opencv, ironpython

I'm working on a project which involves image processing being done in Python and finally the result must be displayed on a WPF UI. I've heard that it is possible to pass data (integer, string, ... etc) between C# and Python using Ironpython, but I couldn't find any solution for my problem. Can somebody help me out, I really appreciate it. Thank you !

Comment: Communicate both apps via TCP, a file, a pipe or shared memory and send the image from one to other

Comment: Can you suggest some specific articles for me ? I'm kind of a noobie in all of this .

Comment: The perfect page is Google. search for "TCP server C#" and "TCP client Python".

Comment: Thank a lot Mr Gusman